# Finding nearby cities using Google API

Tags: python, google-maps-api-3, django-rest-framework, google-places-api

I want to get nearby cities from passed latitude and longitude. I have used the geonames and geobytes APIs but want to use Google API for finding nearby cities.

This is my code:

```
def getNearbyCities(self):
    # lat, lon = self.getLatLon()
    # res_url = urlopen('http://gd.geobytes.com/GetNearbyCities?callback=?&radius=100&limit=100&Latitude=' + str(lat) + '&Longitude=' + str(lon))
    res_url = urlopen('http://getnearbycities.geobytes.com/GetNearbyCities?callback=?&radius=100&locationcode=' + str(self.city))

    resp = str(res_url.read())
    print(resp)
    validate_res = resp.split("b'?(")[-1].split(");'")[0]
    validated_res = ast.literal_eval(validate_res)

    cities_nd_distence = []
    for data in validated_res:
        data_tuple = (data[1], data[7])
        if data[1] not in cities_nd_distence:
            cities_nd_distence.append(data_tuple)
    import pprint
    pprint.pprint(cities_nd_distence)
    return cities_nd_distence
```

Comment: Google doesn't provide that (at least not via the Maps API). Use another service or create your own data source.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get cities based on latitude and longitude, you can have a look at https://github.com/coderholic/django-cities

```
from cities.models import City                                                                                

from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point                                                                     

from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Distance                                                   

p = Point(-118, 34, srid=4326)                                                                                

City.objects.annotate(distance=Distance('location', p)).order_by("distance").first()                          

<City: Hacienda Heights>
```

[image]